# message always shown in the same language instead of configuring the browser not to

Tags: jsf, localization, faces-config

I am trying to show a welcoming message in a JSF page in different languages (English or Spanish) depending on the user's browser configuration.

These are the steps I follow:

1-In Netbeans I create a WAR project

2-In the folder Source Packages I create a package named locale, and inside that package, I create 2 files (messages.properties, messages_es.properties)

**messages.properties**

```
greeting = Welcome!
```

**messages_es.properties**

```
greeting = Bienvenido!
```

3-In the folder Web Pages I create the file **index.html**

```
<h:outputText value="#{msg['greeting']}" />
```

4-In faces-config.xml I write this code:

```
<locale-config>
            <default-locale>en</default-locale>
            <supported-locale>es</supported-locale>
        </locale-config>
        <resource-bundle>
            <base-name>locale.messages</base-name>
            <var>msg</var>
        </resource-bundle>
```

When I run the application in my browser always is shown the welcoming message in Spanish (BIenvenido!), also when I change the preference order (Preferences-Content-Language) to show the web page in English.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What's the value of `Accept-Language` request header sent by client?

Comment: This are Firefox language settings: http://postimg.org/image/acii6kozd/ I dom't know if this answers your question. SHould I Install wireshark to see the Accept-Language value?

Comment: You can just find it in browser's HTTP traffic monitor as available via F12 > Network.

Comment: Accept-Language: en,es;q=0.8,es-ES;q=0.6,en-US;q=0.4,de;q=0.2

Comment: @BalusC I finally managed to find the error. I changed the messages.properties file name to messages_en.properties and it works well. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally managed to find the error. I changed the messages.properties file name to messages_en.properties and it works well.

Comment: Thanks for give us the light!!